# Please How can I achieve the desired result

Tags: javascript, node.js, types

Please how can I achieve the desired result?

I want to loop through `myJSONExample` checking if its values are equal to the `ImageID` in the `data`, then create a new object called `desiredResult` and push the element of the `data` there. I have tried couple of methods but I have not been able to achieve the desired result yet. Please help.

```js
const myJSONExample = {
    "duplicates": {
        "0": [
            "3c743933b463cf5cd92d0edd638a7999",
            "8999bd352b672646541c45d71a533c53",
            "8c3856f32b3d8d181523285652335529",
            "d0e7f503c124be209aa1725fcfb2684f"
        ],
        "2": [
            "036b7f3c16099c3a0874fb14fc05e06e",
            "f17aec3e4ec2be9f4520e63b3fce975c"
        ],
        "3": [
            "608d57c7c6f819e6e2b3c891e6f64ea1",
            "da79b47fcba28668967e948cf9b84445",
            "f2e07d00ca9b735fff85912c421d7a8c"
        ],
        "4": [
            "2dbf65cb10acd968c26f29dfaf57169a",
            "8f0db1d0388b89974de32885d7de233b"
        ]
    },
}

const data = [
    {
        "FileName": "IMG_20181003_175429_001.jpg",
        "ImageID": "608d57c7c6f819e6e2b3c891e6f64ea1",
        "imageUrl": "data:image/jpeg;base64............."
    },
        {
        "FileName": "IMG_20181003_175429_002.jpg",
        "ImageID": "f2e07d00ca9b735fff85912c421d7a8c",
        "imageUrl": "data:image/jpeg;base64............."
    },
        {
        "FileName": "IMG_20181003_175429_003.jpg",
        "ImageID": "3c743933b463cf5cd92d0edd638a7999",
        "imageUrl": "data:image/jpeg;base64............."
    },
        {
        "FileName": "IMG_20181003_175429_004.jpg",
        "ImageID": "8f0db1d0388b89974de32885d7de233b",
        "imageUrl": "data:image/jpeg;base64............."
    },
        {
        "FileName": "IMG_20181003_175429_005.jpg",
        "ImageID": "2dbf65cb10acd968c26f29dfaf57169a",
        "imageUrl": "data:image/jpeg;base64............."
    },
        {
        "FileName": "IMG_20181003_175429_006.jpg",
        "ImageID": "da79b47fcba28668967e948cf9b84445",
        "imageUrl": "data:image/jpeg;base64............."
    },
]

const desiredResult = {
    "duplicates": {
        "0": [
          {
        "FileName": "IMG_20181003_175429_003.jpg",
        "ImageID": "3c743933b463cf5cd92d0edd638a7999",
        "imageUrl": "data:image/jpeg;base64............."
    },
        ],
        "2": [
                        {
        "FileName": "IMG_20181003_17541243243243229_002.jpg",
        "ImageID": "036b7f3c16099c3a0874fb14fc05e06e",
        "imageUrl": "data:image/jpeg;base64............."
    },
                            {
        "FileName": "IMG_20181003_175429_002.jpg",
        "ImageID": "f17aec3e4ec2be9f4520e63b3fce975c",
        "imageUrl": "data:image/jpeg;base64............."
    },
        
        ],
        "3": [
                {
        "FileName": "IMG_20181003_175429_002.jpg",
        "ImageID": "f2e07d00ca9b735fff85912c421d7a8c",
        "imageUrl": "data:image/jpeg;base64............."
    },
        ],
        "4": [
        {
        "FileName": "IMG_20181003_175429_005.jpg",
        "ImageID": "2dbf65cb10acd968c26f29dfaf57169a",
        "imageUrl": "data:image/jpeg;base64............."
    },
            {
        "FileName": "IMG_20181003_175429_004.jpg",
        "ImageID": "8f0db1d0388b89974de32885d7de233b",
        "imageUrl": "data:image/jpeg;base64............."
    },
        ]
    },
}
```

Comment: Do those key number `0`, `2`, `3`, `4` in `myJSONExample` have any meaning for what you are tring to achieve? or you want to just check if the `ImageID` present in any of those?

Comment: @EvgenyKlimenchenko Both approaches would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const myJSONExample = {
  "duplicates": {
    "0": [
      "3c743933b463cf5cd92d0edd638a7999",
      "8999bd352b672646541c45d71a533c53",
      "8c3856f32b3d8d181523285652335529",
      "d0e7f503c124be209aa1725fcfb2684f"
    ],
    "2": [
      "036b7f3c16099c3a0874fb14fc05e06e",
      "f17aec3e4ec2be9f4520e63b3fce975c"
    ],
    "3": [
      "608d57c7c6f819e6e2b3c891e6f64ea1",
      "da79b47fcba28668967e948cf9b84445",
      "f2e07d00ca9b735fff85912c421d7a8c"
    ],
    "4": [
      "2dbf65cb10acd968c26f29dfaf57169a",
      "8f0db1d0388b89974de32885d7de233b"
    ]
  },
}

const data = [{
    "FileName": "IMG_20181003_175429_001.jpg",
    "ImageID": "608d57c7c6f819e6e2b3c891e6f64ea1",
    "imageUrl": "data:image/jpeg;base64............."
  },
  {
    "FileName": "IMG_20181003_175429_002.jpg",
    "ImageID": "f2e07d00ca9b735fff85912c421d7a8c",
    "imageUrl": "data:image/jpeg;base64............."
  },
  {
    "FileName": "IMG_20181003_175429_003.jpg",
    "ImageID": "3c743933b463cf5cd92d0edd638a7999",
    "imageUrl": "data:image/jpeg;base64............."
  },
  {
    "FileName": "IMG_20181003_175429_004.jpg",
    "ImageID": "8f0db1d0388b89974de32885d7de233b",
    "imageUrl": "data:image/jpeg;base64............."
  },
  {
    "FileName": "IMG_20181003_175429_005.jpg",
    "ImageID": "2dbf65cb10acd968c26f29dfaf57169a",
    "imageUrl": "data:image/jpeg;base64............."
  },
  {
    "FileName": "IMG_20181003_175429_006.jpg",
    "ImageID": "da79b47fcba28668967e948cf9b84445",
    "imageUrl": "data:image/jpeg;base64............."
  },
]

let desiredResult = {
  duplicates: Object.keys(myJSONExample.duplicates)
    .reduce(function(prev, key) {
      prev[key] = data
        .filter(function(item) {
          return myJSONExample.duplicates[key].indexOf(item.ImageID) >= 0;
        });
      return prev;
    }, {})
}

console.log(desiredResult);
```